# Where's the JVM path for Java 6 / 1.6 OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I can find the latest update for Java 1.8 at

`ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/`

which only lists

`jdk1.8.0_05.jdk`

and not the [Java 1.6](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US) that I installed following updating to Yosemite?

I need Java 6 for a legacy product that I'm maintaining, and the eclipse IDE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since's it's the last version of Java that built and maintained by Apple it's on a different path, under `/System` and not `/Library`:

`>ls -l  /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/`

Gives:

```
1.4     1.4.2       1.5     1.5.0       1.6     1.6.0
A       Current     CurrentJDK
```

Running this command `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` shows the locations of the various installed Java versions, sample output:

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (3):
    1.8.0_25, x86_64:   "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Comment: It's a Q&A, but it still follows stackoverflows delay of 2 days before accepting ones own answer.